# Is it possible to conditionally disable movableRows?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tabulator

Is there any possibility to disable movableRows conditionally?

Im using Tabulator 4.9

Comment: hard to tell - your code looks a little, erm, missing

Comment: This seems like something that would be covered in the docs.